# javascript library / jquery plugin that generates editable "tags"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure the title of this question is a bit confusing.  An example of what I am looking for is located on the [evite.com's add guests page](http://new.evite.com/#create/guests%3aid=btn_add_guests).  Notice that it allows you to type in email addresses into a text box.  When you hit "space", it validates the email address (based on syntax) and wraps it in an element, complete with appropriate style.  It also allows you to click on an "x" next to the email address to remove the address or click on the address to edit it.

I'm not as concerned with the specifics surrounding email address validation.  I'm more interested in the generic behavior of this component.  Specifically, wrapping some text entered by the user in an element after detecting some hotkey.

Before I re-invent the wheel, I'd like to know if there is some sort of a jquery plugin that already does something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462658/jquery-input-tag-plugins

It contains links to several jQuery plugins, such as [TagManager](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager) and [jQuery TagIt](http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/).

Also contains the following answer:

> The Stack Overflow tag system is "heavily inspired" by this plug-in -
>   http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/
>   Source - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102510/can-i-use-the-tag-textbox-script

Comment: Looks like TagIt does will fill most of my needs.  If I need to add any additional behaviors, I'll be sure to fork and issue a pull request.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used it in a couple of projects and works really well:
http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/

Demos:
http://webspirited.com/tagit/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  TagIt appears to be something I should consider using.